# Java: proving that DCL is not working

Tags: java, concurrency

I wonder whether it's possible reliably to prove that double checked locking is broken:

```
public static Singleton getInstanceDC() {
  if (_instance == null) {                // Single Checked
    synchronized (Singleton.class) {
      if (_instance == null) {        // Double checked
        _instance = new Singleton();
      }
    }
 }
 return _instance;
}
```

Is there any reliable way to create a test or program which shows that it doesn't work? Is there any formal verification proof?

Comment: I suspect just plain logging might give you an insight, i.e. when two concurrent threads are invoking the method, one is actually initializing the singleton and the other is checking for `null`. It would be heuristic, but you could see the inconsistency taking place within a short time frame.

Comment: No. The real issue is that Java can reorder the statements. That's why it is broken. Not because it is obvious on inspection, but because in practice it was discovered to have serious deficiencies.

Comment: Why have you tagged this question as related to the Digital Command Language (`dcl`)? I don't see the connection.

Comment: @HABO thanks for spotting, i will remove it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what I was looking for:
there is java tool called [jcstress](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jcstress/), it's used to verify correctness of JVM.

More precisely sourcecode of DCL test case could be found here:
http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jcstress/file/9270b927e00f/tests-custom/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jcstress/tests/singletons/UnsafeDCL.java#l71

I would say this is proof-by-the-spec :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this [DoubleCheckTest class](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckTest.java)?

This is a *test case showing that it doesn't work*.

I found this example via this [page](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html). The author of this test is Paul Jakubik.